not able to track entire request end to end in langchain + langfuse
I am using langchain with langfuse and its working fine for individual LLM call tracking but my end goal is to track end to end request in one trace, and I am not able to find my method to do that activity
here are sample code
```

class Demo:
def create_handler(self, user_identifier, trace_name):
langfuse_handler = CallbackHandler(
session_id=user_identifier,
metadata={"a": "b"},
trace_name=trace_name,
)
return langfuse_handler
def method1(self, question, llm, prompt, user_identifier):
    langfuse_handler = self.create_handler(user_identifier, "topic_classification")
    retrieval_chain = (
        {"question": RunnablePassthrough()} | prompt | llm
    )
    output_data = retrieval_chain.invoke(
        {"question": question},
        config={
            "callbacks": [langfuse_handler],
        },
    )
    return output_data  # Simulating classification output like "sports", "politics", etc.

def method2(self, question, llm, prompt, user_identifier):
    langfuse_handler = self.create_handler(user_identifier, "RAG_sports")
    retrieval_chain = (
        {"question": RunnablePassthrough()} | prompt | llm
    )
    output_data = retrieval_chain.invoke(
        {"question": question},
        config={
            "callbacks": [langfuse_handler],
        },
    )
    return output_data  # Return RAG-based response for "sports"

def method3(self, question, llm, prompt, user_identifier):
    langfuse_handler = self.create_handler(user_identifier, "RAG_other")
    retrieval_chain = (
        {"question": RunnablePassthrough()} | prompt | llm
    )
    output_data = retrieval_chain.invoke(
        {"question": question},
        config={
            "callbacks": [langfuse_handler],
        },
    )
    return output_data  # Return RAG-based response for non-sports


   class RequestInput(BaseModel):
   question: str
   user_identifier: str
   demo_instance = Demo()

   llm = "Llama"  
    prompt_classification = "classification_prompt"  
    prompt_rag_sports = "sport_promot"  
    prompt_rag_other = "rag_prompt" 


   @app.post("/get_response/")
  async def get_response(request: RequestInput):

class_identification = demo_instance.method1(
    question=request.question,
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt_classification,
    user_identifier=request.user_identifier
)
if class_identification == "sports":
    final_output = demo_instance.method2(
        question=request.question,
        llm=llm,
        prompt=prompt_rag_sports,
        user_identifier=request.user_identifier
    )
else:
    final_output = demo_instance.method3(
        question=request.question,
        llm=llm,
        prompt=prompt_rag_other,
        user_identifier=request.user_identifier
    )
return {"final_output": final_output} ```

here for each request, it first goes to classification and suppose it classify as sports then go to method2 else method3, now I want to track entire user journey in trace, ideally langfuse should support it as I am using same handler but its creating two different rows as trace, If I track in last state then also it misses the first classification.
Can someone please let me know what I am missing ?
Note: langfuse is based on open-telemetry standards
